# How to notify user in some way when using change detection in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I am using Angular ChangeDetection onPushStrategy for updating the DOM whenever the data is changed. And it is working fine as expected, but now I want to first notify user before updating the changes into the DOM as well on the screen. I tried finding it, but failed. Can someone help me with this. 
  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can implement OnChange cycle.
Inside ngOnChange function, check if you got any change and make you logic there.

```
export class YourComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() yourInput;
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if(changes.yourInput) {
            // YOUR LOGIC
        }
    }
}
```